# Find a function that maps (0,1) into, but not onto

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

> Find a $1–1$ function that maps $(0,1)$ into, but not necessarily onto, $S$. Where $S$ is the set of points in the open unit square; that is, $S = {(x, y) : 0 < x, y < 1}.$ (This is easy.)

After thinking and rereading about an hour I give up trying answer the question. Especially, when the author states, that it is trivial. Nothing comes to my mind :(.

Can you, please, help me? In general, are there any systematic ways to answer such kind of questions, rather than guessing a function (as it is so far in the textbook: Understanding Analysis, Stephen Abbott)?

Comment: Think about a picture.  Can you draw a line segment in a unit square?

Comment: It's so obvious that $t\mapsto(t,t)$ is an answer, that you are probably misunderstanding what you are being asked.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos To be honest I am not even sure if I understand the question. Can you, please, elaborate? From what  lulu wrote must I find a line segment that doesn't touch the borders of the unit square?

Comment: I understand it like find a function that takes the values from $(0,1)$ and make it to ''fit'' in the unit square.

Comment: @SargisIskandaryan Sure. And the segment that I chose is one of the diagonals of the square. That's what the points of the form $(t,t)$ ($t\in(0,1)$) are, right?!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It seems to me that I started to understand. Thank you! Now I will spend some time with similar kind of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on some of the comments to the question itself:

For

$x \in (0, 1), \tag 1$

set

$f(x) = (x, x) \in S; \tag 2$

it is clear that $f$ is not onto, since for any

$(y, z) \in S \; \text{with} \; y \ne z \tag 3$

there is no $x \in (0, 1)$ with

$f(x) = (x, x) = (y, z), \tag 4$

since this leads to the contradiction

$x = y \ne z = x. \tag 5$

On the other hand, $f$ is injective since

$f(x_1) = f(x_2) \Longrightarrow (x_1, x_1) = (x_2, x_2) \Longrightarrow x_1 = x_2. \tag 6$